# Emacs 24 - Duplex Print a Buffer

Tags: emacs, printing

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on Linux Mint 17.1.  My printer is an HP Officejet-Pro 8610.  I'd like to know how to duplex-print any given Emacs buffer.

My *PS Setup* buffer has the lines

```
ps-lpr-switches '("-o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble")
ps-spool-duplex t
```

I can print one-sided, but I can't duplex-print.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion.
I've put it into my emacs initialization file, thus:

```
;; Double sided printing
(setq ps-lpr-switches '("-o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble"))
(setq ps-spool-duplex t)
```

and I started to get double sided prints.